# Javascript doesn't work in IE, works fine in everything else

Tags: javascript, toggle

I am new to JavaScript and tried putting together an **FAQs section** that limits the number of shown answers to just 1 at a time. The JavaScript is here (also live at http://indulge.cc/indulge.js). For the whole live site, check out http://www.indulge.cc. You will see in FF, Chrome, Safari, etc. that the FAQs bit works, but doesn't go in IE. Don't know what I missed. Syntax?

```
function showonlyone(shownanswer)
{
    var faqswitcher = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
    for (var x=0; x<faqswitcher.length; x++)
    {
        name = faqswitcher[x].getAttribute('class');
        if (name == 'faqswitcher')
        {
            if (faqswitcher[x].id == shownanswer)
            {
                if (faqswitcher[x].style.display == 'block')
                {
                    faqswitcher[x].style.display = 'none';
                }
                else 
                {
                    faqswitcher[x].style.display = 'block';
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                faqswitcher[x].style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `var name = faqswitcher[x].className;` instead of the `getAttribute()` call.

Comment: I'd recommend learning how to use IE's built-in JS error reporting to see what it says the problem is. Worth finding for future reference anyway. Does IE still show the notice by default?

Comment: Use Shift + F12 for the IE developer engine where you'll get error reporting and more. The usual problem is a comma behind the last declaration of some property list, but I can't find such a problem/case in your code. But the error reporting would help.

Comment: @Pointy - Tried the line of code you gave, still worked on all other browsers except IE.

Comment: Have you checked the IE developer tools? (What IE version is this anyway?)

Comment: Keep getting this error: The value of the property 'showonlyone' is null or undefined, not a function object. Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm in IE 9. Doesn't seem to work in compatibility mode down to 7 or 8 either. Do I need to play with the =, ==, or ===?

Answer (score 0):

Get the class attribute by querying the className property, instead of going after the attribute.

name = faqswitcher[x].className;

It works as well in the other browsers, and older IE's require it.

Comment: Sorry @Pointy, I took you too literally. "var name = faqswitcher..." didn't work, but "name = faqswitcher..." did. Thanks to you and kennebec, for making me realize what I did.